# Why my mesh suddenly become dot2 mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

I'm not sure how the mesh turn into dot2 mesh. I'm in the midst of editting my model suddenly im not sure which button/option I press the mesh turnout like this.

How to turn back my dot2 mesh into normal face mesh?

Comment: You've probably added a particle system to it

Comment: "dot2" is not a term in Blender...